# Allow an "unvote" to delete on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51

Since voting to delete works like a downvote on SO, I'd like to be able to reverse my vote. I may have misunderstood the question at first, or it may have been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are no longer using delete votes this way.